# Possible bug in Help Center > Contact

Tags: bug, design, help-center

Under Help Center > Contact i.e., https://stackoverflow.com/contact,

When I clicked on `I need to delete my user profile`, and then selected `I lost my password` (without clicking on <kbd>X</kbd>), both dialog boxes (**or two same ones?**) get overlapped.

[image: Contact form - Two dialogs on top of each other]

Ideally (when I tried this for other options), the first dialog box was closed automatically, before displaying the new one.

Is this a minor bug or am I overthinking?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, this is definitely a bug.**

The problem isn't exactly related to selecting a second option though. It's with the first dialog, as it does not close properly when selecting the "I need to delete my user profile" option.

When selecting that option and then clicking away, the dialog closes and *immediately reopens*. Then, when you select another option, the new dialog appears on top of the should-be-closed one (whose text gets updated to match the new one - can be any option, not necessarily the "lost password" one). That does not happen with the other options.